# Binding inside Style

Tags: c#, wpf, vb.net, xaml

I have the following piece of code:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type ribbon:Button}">
        <Setter Property="ToolTip" Value="{Binding Label}" />
</Style>
```

This works fine, but why doesn't this works or what is the correct way of doing this:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type ribbon:Button}">
        <Setter Property="ToolTip">
                <Setter.Value>
                <ToolTip Content="{Binding Label}" />  
        </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
</Style>
```

The reason of doing the same is i wanted to change other property of Tooltips like placement etc.. which is only possible by 2nd method

Comment: I don't see any reason why you 2nd approach won't work. Both should be fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the "long form" of the setter that you're after:

```
<Setter Property="ToolTip">
    <Setter.Value>
        <Binding>
            <Binding.Path>Label</Binding.Path>
        </Binding>
    </Setter.Value>
</Setter>
```

---

**Edit #1** Actually, I tested your version and it also seems to work exactly as well.  But it's not exactly correct, because you're setting the ToolTip's content to be another ToolTip.

**Edit #2** Set the ToolTip Placement like this:

```
<Setter Property="ToolTip.Placement" Value="MousePoint" />
```

Comment: It seems you are right, but then how will one change / set different property of tooltip from style like Tooltip Placement